# how to get the Id of the newly created approval request, if the record is submitted to the approval by using process builder

Tags: unit-test, approval-process

i have a test method,creating a record then submitting to the approval by using process builder,then i have to approve the approval request,

```
@isTest
private class RequireRejectionCommentTest
{

     private static testmethod void testRejectionWithoutComment()
    {

        Id testWorkItemId = generateObject();
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest testRej = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        testRej.setComments('');
        testRej.setAction  ('Reject');      
        testRej.setWorkitemId(testWorkItemId );



            try
            {
                Approval.ProcessResult testRejResult =  Approval.process(testRej);
                system.assert(true, 'A rejection with no comment should cause an exception');
            }
            catch(DMLException e)
            {
                system.assertEquals('Please provide a rejection reason!', 
                                    e.getDmlMessage(0), 
                  'Please provide a rejection reason!'); 
            }

    }

 private static Id generateObject()
    {

        TR_Currency_Approval__c testIS = new TR_Currency_Approval__c();
        testIS.Active__c=true;
        insert testIS;

  return Id;
    }
}
```

in the generateObject method i need to get the id of the approval request submitted by process builder.
if we are submitting the record for approval programmatically,we used to wrte something like this

```
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest testReq = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest(); testReq.setObjectId(testIS.Id);
 Approval.ProcessResult reqResult = Approval.process(testReq);
 return reqResult.getNewWorkitemIds()[0];
```

I struck here please help me out guys, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First You can create an approval request.Like method below.

```
public void submitApproval(Object obj)
    {
        // Create an approval request for the Repective object
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Submitting request for approve');
        req1.setObjectId(obj.id);
        req1.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {obj.Next_Approver__c});

        // Submit the approval request for the respective object
        Approval.ProcessResult results = Approval.process(obj);

    }
```

Class ProcessSubmitRequest is used to automatically submit the approval process. We need to set following items while submitting the approval process using trigger:

1. Comment
2. TargetObjectId
3. NextApproverIds – if needed. Here Custom
   logic can be written to dynamically set approver for approval
   process. In this case I am using the custom field present on the
   Opportunity.

You can then approve and reject records cover all the usecases.

The following post will explain you briefly about every use case.[Dynamic approval process](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/dynamic-approval-process-based-on-the-apex-and-trigger/)